# Symfony2 fixtures with order - better way

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixtures

In DoctrineFixturesBundle if I want execute fixtures in specified order i have to create in any fixture class method like this:

```
public function getOrder()
{
    return 2;
}
```

It isn't comfortable way to specify order.

In Laravel Framework I can Do this like this:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call('PositionsSeeder');
        $this->call('UsersSeeder');
        $this->call('PostsSeeder');
    }
}
```

My question is: can I do it in this way in symfony?

I see one solution. I can make BaseFixture with this code:

```
class LoadBrandData extends AbstractFixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        (new LoadPositionsData())->load(manager);
        (new LoadUsersData())->load(manager);
        (new LoadPostsData())->load(manager);

    }
}
```

But maybe i can do this better. Can I?

Comment: I'd also suggest checking https://github.com/nelmio/alice. I prefer it over fixtures due to simpler api and speed. Depends on your workflow of course, take it as inspiration. Symfony integration via: https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you don't like it, the best way to achieve this is through the `getOrder()` method.

Having said that, there are at least two tricks you can use to set the order in other way:

- Define all the fixtures in one single file. It only makes sense if you don't define a lot of fixtures.
- Define all the fixtures in one single directory and put the load order as part of the file name (they are loaded alphabetically). This only works if you follow the single-bundle approach to develop Symfony apps.

Answer (score 10):

You can use Doctrine **DependentFixtureInterface**; please check below example:

```
namespace MyDataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class MyFixture extends AbstractFixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {}

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return array('MyDataFixtures\MyOtherFixture'); // fixture classes fixture is dependent on
    }
}

class MyOtherFixture extends AbstractFixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {}
}
```

Source: https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do.

Create a class that will store an order of load.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures;

use AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadClientData;
use AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadRoleData;
use AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData;

class Order
{
    const FIXTURES = [
        LoadRoleData::class,
        LoadUserData::class,
        LoadClientData::class,
    ];
}
```

Then, in your abstract fixture class (the one that will be inherited by all other fixtures), create the following method:

```
    /**
     * @return int
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        $order = array_search(get_called_class(), Order::FIXTURES);

        if ($order === false) {
            throw new \Exception('Seems like you forgot to put things in Order');
        }

        return $order;
    }
```

You should never call the `getOrder` method directly from the fixture itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also name your fixtures files with a prefix

```
00-MyFirstFixtures.php
01-MySecondFixtures.php
02-MyThirdFixtures.php
```

...etc

Obviously, don't forget to name you class the same way

```
class 00-MyFirstFixtures extends Fixture
{
  ...
}
```